# Error in method to visualize missing values

Tags: r, na

I am trying to visualize missing values (NA) in a data.frame containing the Hepatitis dataset and using the package `VIM`. I am trying to do that by using the function `spineMiss`:

```
spineMiss(hepatitis[, c("PRONOSTICO", "PROTIME")])
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in createPlot(main, sub, xlab, ylab, labels): (list) object
>   cannot be coerced to type 'double'

This the `str` of the dataframe:

[image]

If I use the function like this:

```
a <- hepatitis$PRONOSTICO
b <- hepatitis$PROTIME
spineMiss(c(a,b))
```

I do not get any error, but the result does not make much sense. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the `str(hepatitis)`

Comment: I have edited the question to add that information @akrun

Comment: It shows `PRONOSTICO` as `factor` and not `numeric`

Answer (score 1):

The `data` in the documentation is working correctly

```
library(VIM)
data(tao, package = "VIM")
## for missing values
spineMiss(tao[, c("Air.Temp", "Humidity")])
```

and both the columns are `numeric`

```
str(tao[, c("Air.Temp", "Humidity")])
#'data.frame':  736 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Air.Temp: num  27.1 27 27 26.9 26.8 ...
# $ Humidity: num  79.6 75.8 76.5 76.2 76.4 76.7 76.5 78.3 78.6 76.9 ...
```

As one of the column is `factor`, it could be used as the first variable.  It is not giving any errors

```
set.seed(24)
hepatitis <- data.frame(PROTIME = sample(c(NA, 80:95), 100,
  replace = TRUE), PRONOSTICO = sample(c("FALLECE", "VIVE"), 
 100, replace = TRUE))

spineMiss(hepatitis[c("PRONOSTICO", "PROTIME")])
```

Comment: I have used you code, chaging the dataframe and the column names with mines. But it still gives me the same error. @akrun

Comment: @Sergio6Rey because I thought it is a `list` column, but instead the column `PRONOSTICO` is `factor`

Comment: @Sergio6Rey. According to the documentation `if the variable of interest is categorical, either a logical indicating whether labels should be plotted below each cell, or a character vector giving the labels. This is ignored if the variable of interest is numeric.`

Comment: I do not understand very much your comment. I converted the column PRONOSTICO to  numeric but it still gives the same error. @akrun

Comment: @Sergio6Rey Give me 5 mins, let me create a reproducible example as you didn't provide an example

Comment: @Sergio6Rey It is not giving an error with `set.seed(24);
 hepatitis <- data.frame(PROTIME = sample(c(NA, 80:95), 100, replace = TRUE), PRONOSTICO = sample(c("FALLECE", "VIVE"), 100, replace = TRUE));spineMiss(hepatitis)` what is your expected

Answer (score 0):

I got the conclusion that the error was related with the structure of the data.frame itself. It was not created by me with R code but read from a file. After the reading I have done some preprocessing (type conversion, etc). The `str(hepatitis)` shows that the original specification of the attributes of the data.frame are still stored in it. I do not understand completely how that makes `spineMiss` malfunction but certainly that is the root of the problem.

I have solved it by creating a new data.frame and copying all the data of the previous one (the read from a file and preprocessed) in it:

```
aux <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 20, nrow = 0))
colnames(aux) <- atributos
for(i in 1:nrow(hepatitis)){
  aux[i,] = hepatitis[i,]
}
spineMiss(aux[, c("PRONOSTICO", "PROTIME")])
```

Comment: If it is to remove the attributes, May be you just `as.data.frame(hepatitis)` may work

Comment: Correct, that also works and it is a similar but simplier solution @akrun